# Modifying a subsection of an Rcpp::List in a Separate Function by Reference

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I would like to be able, via a function, to modify a sub part of a `Rcpp::List`. Since `Rcpp::List` is a pointer to some R data, I thought it would be possible to do something like this:

```
void modifyList(Rcpp::List l) {
  l["x"] = "x";
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List rcppTest() {
  Rcpp::List res;
  res["a"] = Rcpp::List::create();
  modifyList(res["a"]);
  return res;
}
```

I expected to get as return value of `rcppTest` a list with an element "x" of value "x". The returned list is empty however.

If instead I use the signature `modifyList(Rcpp::List& l)`, I get a compilation error

```
rcppTest.cpp:17:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Rcpp::Vector<19, PreserveStorage>::NameProxy' (aka 'generic_name_proxy<19, PreserveStorage>') to 'Rcpp::List &' (aka 'Vector<19> &') for 1st argument
```

How can I modify a a sub part of an `Rcpp::List` via a function ?

Comment: I think that has been discussed before (possibly in the contect of `DataFrame` object, which are really `List` underneath) -- it just won't work reason of the R types under it.  So you mayl have to write a helper functions that copies the existing list and then alters.  Or keep an STL list as long as possible and convert just before return...

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879038/how-can-i-add-a-new-column-to-dataframe-in-rcpp) for a similar problem. Your example will work if `modifyList` returns the list and the result is properly assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, modifying a list by reference isn't possible. In this case, you *must* return the `Rcpp::List` as @RalfStubner points out from the comments.

e.g.

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// Specified return type of List
Rcpp::List modifyList(Rcpp::List l) {
  l["x"] = "x";
  return l;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List rcppTest() {
  Rcpp::List res;
  res["a"] = Rcpp::List::create();

  // Store result back into "a"
  res["a"] = modifyList(res["a"]);

  return res;
}
```

Test:

```
rcppTest()
# $a
# $a$x
# [1] "x"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void modifyList(List& l, std::string i) {
  l[i]= "x";
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List rcppTest() {
  Rcpp::List res;
  res["a"] = Rcpp::List::create();
  modifyList(res,"a");
  return res;
}
```

and gives:

```
> rcppTest()
$`a`
[1] "x"
```

The problem is you are trying to:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Rcpp::List& {aka Rcpp::Vector<19>&}'
```