# Rcpp: Which is the best way to modify some columns of a dataframe with Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Usually I have to work with big spatial data, and high speed and memory efficiency are expected.
Supposing I want to modify some numeric columns of a dataframe with a self-defined function in Rcpp, I am confused about the reference and copy mechanism of C++ and Rcpp. With the three minimal example code below, would you please help me clatifying the following questions:

1. Is updateDF3 the best function to do such a task with the highest speed and lowest memory required?
   This function is modified from a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731106/passing-by-reference-a-data-frame-and-updating-it-with-rcpp#), but I do not understand the warning given by the author, "There are issues associated with this approach. Your original data frame and the one you created share the same vectors and so bad things can happen." If I use this function only for a sub function as updateDF3 and called from R, is it safe?
2. Why is the difference of performance of updateDF1 and updateDF2 not significant?
   What is the difference between passing the parameter with or without reference (&)?
3. Is the function coded pooly and there is another way, such as DataFrame out=clone(df), tmpstr=asstd::string(colnames[v])?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std; 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool contains(CharacterVector x, std::string y) { 
  return std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), y)!=x.end(); 
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame updateDF1(DataFrame df, Nullable<Rcpp::CharacterVector> vars=R_NilValue) {
  DataFrame out=clone(df);
  string tmpstr;
  NumericVector tmpv;
  if(vars.isNotNull()){
    CharacterVector selvars(vars);
    for(int v=0;v<selvars.size();v++){
      tmpstr=as<std::string>(selvars[v]);
      tmpv=df[tmpstr];
      tmpv=tmpv+1.0;
      out[tmpstr]=tmpv;
    }
  }
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame updateDF2(DataFrame& df, Nullable<Rcpp::CharacterVector> vars=R_NilValue) {
  DataFrame out=clone(df);
  string tmpstr;
  NumericVector tmpv;
  if(vars.isNotNull()){
    CharacterVector selvars(vars);
    for(int v=0;v<selvars.size();v++){
      tmpstr=as<std::string>(selvars[v]);
      tmpv=df[tmpstr];
      tmpv=tmpv+1.0;
      out[tmpstr]=tmpv;
    }
  }
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List updateDF3(DataFrame& df, Nullable<Rcpp::CharacterVector> vars=R_NilValue) {
  List out(df.size());
  CharacterVector colnames=df.attr("names");
  string tmpstr;
  NumericVector tmpv;
  
  for(int v=0;v<df.size();v++){
    if(vars.isNotNull()){  
      CharacterVector selvars(vars); 
      tmpstr=as<std::string>(colnames[v]);
      if(contains(selvars,tmpstr)){
        tmpv=df[tmpstr];
        tmpv=tmpv+1.0;
        out[v]=tmpv;
      }else{
        out[v]=df[tmpstr];
      }
    }else{
      out[v]=df[tmpstr];
    }
  }
  out.attr("class") = df.attr("class") ;
  out.attr("row.names") = df.attr("row.names") ;
  out.attr("names") = df.attr("names") ;
  return out;
}


/*** R

df=as.data.frame(matrix(1:120000000,nrow=10000000))
names(df)=paste("band",1:ncol(df),sep="_")
df=cbind(x="charcol",df)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  x1<<-updateDF1(df,vars=names(df)[-1]),
  x2<<-updateDF2(df,vars=names(df)[-1]),
  x3<<-updateDF3(df,vars=names(df)[-1]),
  times=10
)
identical(x1,x2)
identical(x1,x3)
*/
```

```
##performance
#Unit: milliseconds
#                                       expr      min       lq     mean   median
# x1 <<- updateDF1(df, vars = names(df)[-1]) 587.6023 604.9242 711.8981 651.1242
# x2 <<- updateDF2(df, vars = names(df)[-1]) 581.7129 641.2876 882.9999 766.9354
# x3 <<- updateDF3(df, vars = names(df)[-1]) 406.1824 417.5892 542.2559 420.8485
```

Comment: AFAICS, none of your functions modifies the original data.frame. All of them make copies or create a new data.frame. It would be fastest to modify `df`. You could do that by removing the definition of `out` from `updateDF2` and search and replacing `out` with `df`. Would it be an option to use package data.table? For the simple task you show here that would be much better.

Comment: @Roland Thanks. There is really a remarkable performance gain without clone by modifying updateDF2. But I have learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731106/passing-by-reference-a-data-frame-and-updating-it-with-rcpp) that 'The way DataFrame::operator[] is implemented indeed leeds to a copy when you do that:
df["newCol"] = newCol', so originially I think I should never update the column of a df in Rcpp for many times, however, from the above example it show that it is more faster than newly create a dataframe. Could you tell my why? Is it the new feature of Rcpp?

Comment: @Roland I will update the question and labeld as the best answer with the modifed updateDF2 as the best answer. data.table is not the option because there will be a complex self-defined function executed on the column and cycle by group which I prefere to coding within Rcpp. Thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: "executed on the column and cycle by group" data.table excels at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the suggestion of @Roland, the best way using a reference method by modifying updateDF2, the code is as below:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame updateDF(DataFrame& df, Nullable<Rcpp::CharacterVector> vars=R_NilValue) {
  string tmpstr;
  NumericVector tmpv;
  if(vars.isNotNull()){
    CharacterVector selvars(vars);
    for(int v=0;v<selvars.size();v++){
      tmpstr=selvars[v];
      tmpv=df[tmpstr];
      tmpv=tmpv+1.0;
      df[tmpstr]=tmpv;
    }
  }
  return df;
}
```

with the performance of:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                       expr      min       lq     mean   median
 x1 <<- updateDF1(df, vars = names(df)[-1]) 573.8246 728.4211 990.8680 951.3108
 x2 <<- updateDF2(df, vars = names(df)[-1]) 595.7339 694.0645 935.4226 941.7450
 x3 <<- updateDF3(df, vars = names(df)[-1]) 197.7855 206.4767 377.4378 225.0290
 x4 <<- updateDF(df, vars = names(df)[-1])  148.5119 149.7321 247.1329 152.3744
```

Comment: `updateDF` modifies `df`. You don't need to assign `x4 <<- `. (You don't need `<<-` within `microbenchmark` anyway, `<-` suffices.)

Comment: @Roland Thanks for further clarifying. I have noticed the modified df in R when calling the Rcpp subfunction updateDF, this will bring in  risk for new users and should be take cautious. And I do not think data.table is the best option for some of my work because I have more than 100 million groups for loop, I think it is more fast with a loop in Rcpp. Am I right?

Comment: That depends on the function but you are probably not right.